# an easy explanation of where to and how to use condition variables?

Tags: operating-system, condition-variable, nachos

I have searched google for nearly 2 hours to get an idea of what are the situations of using condition variables. But I have found nothing but a bunch of irritating code snippets harder to realize. So I need clear conception regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following link which is like a pseudocode, a guideline of using condition variable. I hope it will greatly help students working on their nachos project or learning pthreads.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview